# Calculating quotient rings

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

How do I go about calculating what $R = \mathbb Z [\sqrt{-5} ] / \langle 1 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle $ actually is (i.e. how do I find a simpler ring isomorphic to $R$)?

I can see that $\langle \sqrt{-5} \rangle \subsetneq \langle 1 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle$, so $R \subsetneq \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}] / \langle \sqrt{-5} \rangle \cong \mathbb Z$. So it's isomorphic to a proper subring of $\mathbb Z$. I can't see how to get any further with this line of reasoning, though.

I can also see that $a + b \sqrt{-5} \equiv a - b \ (\mathrm{mod} \langle 1 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle ) $, and since $4 \in \langle 1 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle $ any element in $R$ is congruent to $0,1,2$ or $3$. How do I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: Ah, ok, it isn't (since $4a = 5$ can't be solved in $\mathbb Z$).

Comment: @DylanMoreland How is that helpful? (I'm not saying that it isn't, I just can't see how it is)

Comment: Actually, $\langle \sqrt{-5}\rangle$ is not contained in $\langle 1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle$; if it were, then the latter would contain $1$ and so be the entire ring. But $1+\sqrt{-5}$ is not a unit, so the principal ideal it generates cannot be all of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. That's the very first error you are making. $\langle \sqrt{-5}\rangle$ and $\langle 1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle$ are incomparable.

Answer (score 5):

Neither $\sqrt{-5}$ nor $4$ is in the ideal $(1 + \sqrt{-5})$, and you can check this directly: write $a + b\sqrt{-5}$, $a, b \in \mathbf Z$ for a general element of $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ and note that
\[
(1 + \sqrt{-5})(a + b\sqrt{-5}) = (a - 5b) + (a + b)\sqrt{-5} = \sqrt{-5}
\]
would give a solution to the system $a - 5b = 0$ and $a + b = 1$ over the integers. Why can't this happen? Similarly for $4$. Another remark is that there are no proper subrings of $\mathbf Z$, and if you were looking at ideals $\mathfrak a \subset \mathfrak b$ in a ring $A$ then $A/\mathfrak b$ would be a *quotient* of $A/\mathfrak a$.

One way of finding the quotient is to view $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ as $\mathbf Z[X]/(X^2 + 5)$. Then $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]/(1 + \sqrt{-5})$ becomes
\[
(\mathbf Z[X]/(X^2 + 5))/(1 + X) \cong (\mathbf Z[X]/(1 + X))/(X^2 + 5) \cong \mathbf Z/(6).
\]

You could use this idea to find out what $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]/(\sqrt{-5})$ actually is!

Comment: Thanks. What about something like $\mathbb Z [\sqrt{-5}] / \langle 2, 1 + \sqrt{-5} \rangle $?

Comment: @Matt Well, what's the image of $2$ in $\mathbf Z/(6)$?

Comment: Someone is going to yell at me for this, so: my subrings have the same $1$ as the larger ring.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**  $\rm\: f : \mathbb Z \rightarrow \rm R$ is onto by $\rm\sqrt{-5}\equiv -1$. $\rm\ ker\ f =$ integer multiples $\rm\:n\:$  of $\:1+\sqrt{-5}\:$ in $\rm\: \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}].\:$

$$\rm 1+\sqrt{-5}\ |\ n\ \ in\ \ \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]\iff \frac{n}{1+\sqrt{-5}}\: =\: \frac{n(1-\sqrt{-5})}6\in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}] \iff\ 6\ |\ n\ \ in\ \ \mathbb Z$$

Thus $\rm\:R\:\cong\:  (im\ f)/(ker\ f)\: \cong\: \mathbb Z/6\:\!\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 3):

As noted by Dylan, we have 
$$
A:=\frac{\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]}{\left(1+\sqrt{-5}\right)}\simeq\frac{\mathbb Z[X]}{\mathfrak a}\quad,
$$
where $\mathfrak a$ is the ideal of $\mathbb Z[X]$ generated by $X^2+5$ and $X+1$.

Claim: $\mathfrak a$ is the kernel of the epimorphism 
$$
\phi:\mathbb Z[X]\to\mathbb Z/(6),\quad p(X)\mapsto p(-1)\bmod6.
$$
This will imply $A\simeq\mathbb Z/(6)$.

The inclusion $\mathfrak a\subset\ker\phi$ is clear.

The equality 
$$
X^2+5=(X+1)\ (X-1)+6
$$ 
shows that $\mathfrak a$ is generated by $X+1$ and $6$.

If $p(X)$ is in $\ker\phi$, then $p(-1)=6n$ for some $n$ in $\mathbb Z$, and the equalities
$$
p(X)=(X+1)\ q(X)+p(-1)=(X+1)\ q(X)+6n,
$$
with $q(X)$ in $\mathbb Z[X]$, imply that $p(X)$ is in $\mathfrak a$.

Comment: Generally, by the Factor or Remainder Theorem, for any ring $\rm R$, for ideals in $\rm\:R[x]\:$ we have $$\rm\: (x-r,\:f(x))\ =\ (x-r,\:f(r)),\quad for\quad r\in R,\ f\in R[x]$$ 

Said in congruence language, for any ideal $\rm\:I\subset R[x]$

$$\rm x-r\in I\ \Rightarrow\ x\equiv r\ \Rightarrow\ f(x)\equiv f(r)\ \ in\ \ R[x]/I$$